# Github Actions Build Artifact Folder Location

Tags: msbuild, github-actions

I'm creating a .net build with github actions. I'm stuck on the last step for my build process, I'd like to automatically add the release folder as the artifact to upload, however, I'm not sure which variable, or if there is one to use to identify. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Example code below:

```
name: Build Capcom
 
on: [push]
 
jobs:
  build:
 
    runs-on: windows-latest
 
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      name: Checkout Code
     
    - name: Setup MSBuild Path
      uses:  warrenbuckley/Setup-MSBuild@v1
       
    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.2
      
      
    - name: Install Windows 8.1 SDK        
      shell: powershell
      run: |
        Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507 -OutFile sdksetup.exe -UseBasicParsing
        Start-Process -Wait sdksetup.exe -ArgumentList "/q", "/norestart", "/features", "OptionId.WindowsDesktopSoftwareDevelopmentKit", "OptionId.NetFxSoftwareDevelopmentKit"
     
    - name: Restore NuGet Packages
      run: nuget restore ExploitCapcom.sln
 
    - name: Build App
      run: msbuild ExploitCapcom.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
 
    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: Capcom
        path: "D:/a/newbuild/"
```

Comment: This is not a question about Github Actions. This is a question about `msbuild` output location. If you look at the [`msbuild` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019), you can see there's a `BaseOutputPath` property (as the doc says: _Specifies the base path for the output file_) you can set it in your `Build App` step to a given value and use the same value as a `path` in the `Upload artifact` step. You can also add `-verbosity:diag` switch to the `msbuild` command to see more detailed build output to know the path.